# OpenLayers/GeoServer layer zooms in and then out again, why?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have a strange ZOOM behavior.  I am using GeoServer 2.6.1/OpenLayers 2.13.1.  I have a layer I created from a MrSid file and am serving as a wms layer.

Lets call it the "problematic" layer.  When I serve this "problematic" layer alone, everything is ok.  When I serve it with a base layer, I get a strange effect:  when I zoom in, the "problematic" layer zooms in, then zooms back out again.

If I click on a check box to hide the "problematic" layer (and only show the base layer which is at correct zoom) and then I click on the check box to show the "problematic" layer again, it aligns correctly with the base layer.

On the GeoServer side, I am "forcing declared" on both the base layer and the "problematic" layer.  The Native SRS and the Declared SRS are both set to EPSG:2236. On the OpenLayers side, I am using the displayProjection setting and have it also set to 2236 as recommend in other threads.

What could be the issue?

OpenLayers Code:

```
var map, baseLayer, problematicLayer;

        // pink tile avoidance
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;


        function init() {

            // Setup Projection
            epsg2236 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2236");

            // Setup Format
            format = 'image/png';

            // Setup Extent
            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    858665.911628, 516256.950565,
                    870969.136, 527480.405429
                );


            // Setup Map Options
            var options = {
                maxExtent: bounds,
                maxResolution: 128.890625,
                projection: epsg2236,
                displayProjection: epsg2236,
                units: 'm'
            };

            // Setup Map
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

            // Setup tiled base layer
            baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "sf:base_lines - Tiled",
                "http://server01:8085/geoserver/sf/wms",
                {
                    "LAYERS": 'sf:base_lines',
                    "STYLES": '',
                    TRANSPARENT: 'true',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                    visibility: true,
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:2236': false }
                }
            );

            // The Problematic Layer
            problematicLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "sf:SID_2014 - Tiled",
                    "http://server01:8085/geoserver/sf/wms",
                {
                    "LAYERS": 'sf:SID_2014',
                    "STYLES": '',
                    TRANSPARENT: 'true',
                    format: format
                },
                {
                    visibility: false,
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:2236': false }
                }
            );


 map.addLayers([baseLayer, problematicLayer]);


// Add MousePosition Control
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

            // Zoom to Max Extent
            if (!map.getCenter()) {
                map.zoomToMaxExtent();
            }
 }
```

**Update #1**

I just uploaded a video of the issue so you can get an exact idea of what I mean by "zooms in and then out again":

https://vimeo.com/119384955

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem myself.  The "temporary" fix is to hide/show the layer before every zoom:

```
// Zoom Changed event
map.events.register("zoomend", map, zoomChanged);

function zoomChanged()
{

    // Hide MrSid  layer (There is a bug when changing zooms, the workaround is to 
    // hide/show layer, if not MrSid layer does not work)
    problematicLayer.setVisibility(false);
    // Show MrSid layer
    problematicLayer.setVisibility(true);

}
```